# Lua Logitech - Sensitivity adjustment

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Good day to everyone.

I want to create a "No Recoil" scenario with the ability to specify my own aiming sensitivity value.

At the moment, the code that you can see below works exclusively with one setting, namely with the dpi800 and the in-game sensitivity on the X and Y axes equal to 7, is it possible to make it so that I can change literally two digits, for example, not 7, but 9 or 10 and so on, and the script changed using some formula values in line 7(r_p["Weapon1"]) and 8(r_p["Weapon2"])

```
local r_p = {Weapon1}
local r_o = r_p[o_s_a] or {Weapon2}
 
local o_s_a = "Weapon2"
local n_o_s_a = {Weapon2 = "Weapon1", Weapon1 = "Weapon2"}
 
r_p["Weapon1"] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 100, -1, 17, 600, -1, 20, 500, -1, 21, 800}
r_p["Weapon2"] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 150, -1, 17, 400, -1, 20, 700, -1, 20, 300, -1, 20, 150, -2, 21, 400, -2, 21, 550, -2, 21, 300, -2, 21, 250, -2, 21, 100}
 
 
function Log()
  if not IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
    ClearLog()
    OutputLogMessage("Current mode: List of weapons | Scroll lock is OFF\n\n")
    OutputLogMessage("Selected:   %s\n\n", o_s_a)
    OutputLogMessage("        (%s) | Weapon1            (%s) | Weapon2\n\n", o_s_a == "Weapon1", o_s_a == "Weapon2")
  end
end
 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and IsModifierPressed("lctrl") and not IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
      o_s_a = n_o_s_a[o_s_a]
      r_o = r_p[o_s_a] or {}
      Log()
    else if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and not IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
        for xy = 3, #r_o, 3 do
          local c_t = GetRunningTime()
          local h_r = r_o[xy-2]
          local v_r = r_o[xy-1]
          local r_d = r_o[xy]
            repeat
              local d_t = GetRunningTime() - c_t, r_d
              MoveMouseRelative(h_r, v_r)
              Sleep(10)
            until d_t >= r_d or not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) or not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) or not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
        end
    end
    end
end
```

I tried using multiplayer, but in this version you can use only 2 values, where sensitivity 12 is standard, when you activate multiplayer, all your sensitivity settings are divided by 2 and as a result you get sensitivity 6, but this is a bit not the option that I need.

Thank you very much for any help if all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the values on-the-fly instead of changing values in lines 7(r_p["Weapon1"]) and 8(r_p["Weapon2"]).
Replace the following lines

```
local h_r = r_o[xy-2]
local v_r = r_o[xy-1]
```

with

```
local h_r = round(r_o[xy-2] * sens / 6)
local v_r = round(r_o[xy-1] * sens / 6)
```

where `sens` is a variable with default value `6`, but you can modify it.
`round` is a function, define it before `OnEvent`:

```
function round(x)
   return math.floor(x + 0.5)
end
sens = 6
```

---

**UPDATE**:

The solution above has a drawback: due to rounding errors, the cursor gradually shifts to the left and/or to the top.
The solution below accumulates fractional parts to avoid such shift.

Define the function `MoveMouseRelativeFractional` which accepts fractional arguments and use it instead of the standard `MoveMouseRelative`.

The definition should be inserted at the very beginning of the whole script:

```
local remainder_fractional_x, remainder_fractional_y = 0, 0
local function MoveMouseRelativeFractional(x, y)
    x = remainder_fractional_x + x
    y = remainder_fractional_y + y
    local x_int = math.floor(x + 0.5)
    local y_int = math.floor(y + 0.5)
    remainder_fractional_x = x - x_int
    remainder_fractional_y = y - y_int
    MoveMouseRelative(x_int, y_int)
end
```

Remove `round`:

```
local h_r = r_o[xy-2] * sens / 13
local v_r = r_o[xy-1] * sens / 13
```

Replace `MoveMouseRelative` with `MoveMouseRelativeFractional`:

```
MoveMouseRelativeFractional(h_r, v_r)
```

Comment: @JesseCor - The answer updated.